# Android: Scrolling to slow on gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, smoothing

i have trouble to speed up the scrolling on gridview when I show the thumbnail on the phone with getThumbnail. I know it's create a thumbnail if not existed. I think of using AsyncTask to create the thumbnail in the background. In my knowledge we can only have limited parallel execution of the AsyncTask.

Does anyone know how to create a smooth scrollable gridvie? Please help. Using cache is good but only if the thumbnail has been cached, but it won't give a smooth scrolling for the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask and start it paralell with

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static <Param, Progress, Result> void startParallel(
            AsyncTask<Param, Progress, Result> task, Param... params) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
        else
            task.execute(params);
    }
```

also use the convertView and ViewHolders if not doing already

Comment: Thanks, I have read similar stuff but i am not quite get how to do it.. If i load each thumbnail with asynctask, then I would have a lot of task at the same time but there is a limit of running these task.

Comment: with the helper method i posted above the threads are running on a threadpoolexecutor and has no limit. just try it out - it will work ;) also just call getThumbnail (in a new asynctask) when the row is displayed - means just in getView of the adapter

Comment: Hello. I have tried but still have this exception saying rejectExecutionException. I am running the old android phone not the latest one

Comment: Actually I changed to use handler instead. But thanks for your help

Comment: no problem - still async task should have worked the same way

Comment: The handler is working but i encounter a problem that may also the reason with rejection on asynctask. My CursorAdapter execute the newView function for every single items in the cursor rather than execute only the visible area of the grid. I have the code on my other post.